# DSC Certificate Update - Method C_GenerateKeyPair returned CKR_General_error with Error Code [5]

Tags: token, signature, dsc

I am trying to Update
My DSC is Expiring Soon But geting Error

now Following the Same steps given in Video but Getting Error After Login
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQGz2RzwX-U

trying to update DSC with New Certificate
Software used For Login - Emclick Utility

[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqurG.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj5v7.png)

Token Details
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrkJa.png)
DSC Software HYP2003 Token Driver for Windows Operating System

I am trying to Update
My DSC is Expiring Soon But geting Error